How to Sign and Verify a File with a Certificate in Azure Key Vault In C#
I am attempting to write a tool to sign and verify files with a certificate in Azure Key Vault.  Previously, our tool kicked off SignTool.exe as a process.  I'd like the new tool to work properly in code.
I have found a lot of examples of how to get an X509 certificate from Azure and use it to sign and then verify the data.
What I can't work out is how I embed the signature in the file and how I verify the file itself.
I've googled this for hours.  All examples in code don't use files.  All file examples use either SignTool.exe or AzureSignTool.exe.  I'm just missing the last piece in the puzzle.
Any help appreciated.  My current code is below.  It's geared to Azure Key Vault but I believe the scenario works with any X509 certificate.
namespace Test.Signing.Shell;

public static class Program
{
    #region Public interface

    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var keyVaultUri = new Uri("KEY_VAULT_URI");
            var tenantId = "TENANT_ID";
            var clientId = "CLIENT_ID";
            var clientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
            var certificateName = "CERTIFICATE_NAME";

            var filePath = @"FILE_PATH";

            var signer = new Signer(keyVaultUri, tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, certificateName);

            signer.SignFile(filePath);

            Console.WriteLine("Sign process complete");

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sign process failed: {e}");

            return 1;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
    

using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace Test.Signing
{
    public class Signer
    {
        public Signer(Uri keyVaultUri, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string certificateName)
        {
            KeyVaultUri = keyVaultUri;
            TenantId = tenantId;
            ClientId = clientId;
            ClientSecret = clientSecret;
            CertificateName = certificateName;
        }

        private Uri KeyVaultUri { get; }

        private string TenantId { get; }

        private string ClientId { get; }

        private string ClientSecret { get; }

        private string CertificateName { get; }

        public void SignFile(string filePath)
        {
            var client = GetSecretClient();

            var certificateSecret = GetCertificateSecret(client);

            var certificate = GetCertificate(certificateSecret);

            SignFile(certificate, filePath);
        }

        private SecretClient GetSecretClient()
        {
            SecretClient secretClient;

            try
            {
                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret);

                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to the key vault...");

                secretClient = new SecretClient(KeyVaultUri, credential);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect to the key vault", ex);
            }

            return secretClient;
        }

        private KeyVaultSecret GetCertificateSecret(SecretClient secretClient)
        {
            KeyVaultSecret secret;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieving the certificate secret...");

                secret = secretClient.GetSecret(CertificateName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve the certificate from the key vault", ex);
            }

            return secret;
        }

        private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(KeyVaultSecret secret)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating the certificate from the secret...");

                var certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);

                 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create the certificate from the secret", ex);
            }

            return certificate;
        }

        private void SignFile(X509Certificate2 certificate, string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
                {
                    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))

                    using (var hashAlgorithm = SHA256.Create())
                    {
                        var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(fileStream);

                        var signature = rsa.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);

                        var signatureIsValid = rsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
                        
                        // QUESTION:  HOW DO I ADJUST THIS CODE TO PUT THE SIGNATURE IN THE FILE AND THEN TO VERIFY THE FILE?

                        if (signatureIsValid)
                            Console.WriteLine("Signature is valid");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Signature is not valid");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to sign file", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}


What I can't work out is how I embed the signature in the file and how I verify the file itself.. Use tools such as AzureSignTool. Signature format is filetype-depended and is quite complicated. This is why these tools exist.
